# Using Butterknife to Bind EditText from DialogFragment

Tags: java, android, butterknife

I am attempting to get Strings from 2 `Edittexts` within a Dialog `Fragment`, but my app keeps crashing when the `activity` starts. It is some sort of issue with being able to bind the `edittexts` from the dialog. I am not sure of the correct way to bind them.

Here is the crash:

```
09-24 11:34:30.366 16147-16147/com.epicodus.concertaid E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.epicodus.concertaid, PID: 16147
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.epicodus.concertaid/com.epicodus.concertaid.ui.UserProfileActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to bind views for com.epicodus.concertaid.ui.UserProfileActivity
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to bind views for com.epicodus.concertaid.ui.UserProfileActivity
 at butterknife.ButterKnife.bind(ButterKnife.java:322)
 at butterknife.ButterKnife.bind(ButterKnife.java:237)
 at com.epicodus.concertaid.ui.UserProfileActivity.onCreate(UserProfileActivity.java:37)
 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required view 'userEmailEditText' with ID 2131558627 for field 'mUserEmailEditText' was not found. If this view is optional add '@Nullable' annotation.
 at butterknife.ButterKnife$Finder.findRequiredView(ButterKnife.java:140)
 at com.epicodus.concertaid.ui.UserProfileActivity$$ViewBinder.bind(UserProfileActivity$$ViewBinder.java:15)
 at com.epicodus.concertaid.ui.UserProfileActivity$$ViewBinder.bind(UserProfileActivity$$ViewBinder.java:8)
 at butterknife.ButterKnife.bind(ButterKnife.java:319)
 at butterknife.ButterKnife.bind(ButterKnife.java:237) 
 at com.epicodus.concertaid.ui.UserProfileActivity.onCreate(UserProfileActivity.java:37) 
 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

And here is the Activity:

```
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.epicodus.concertaid.Constants;
import com.epicodus.concertaid.R;
import com.firebase.client.Firebase;
import com.firebase.client.FirebaseError;
import butterknife.Bind;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;

public class UserProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

@Bind(R.id.summaryTextView) TextView mSummaryTextView;
@Bind(R.id.deleteAccountButton) Button mDeleteAccountButton;
@Bind(R.id.userEmailEditText) EditText mUserEmailEditText;
@Bind(R.id.userPasswordEditText) EditText mUserPasswordEditText;

private Firebase mFirebaseRef;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_profile);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    mDeleteAccountButton.setOnClickListener(this);


    //GET REFERENCE TO FIREBASE
    mFirebaseRef = new Firebase(Constants.FIREBASE_URL);

    //SETS FONT FOR TITLE
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/MUSICNET.ttf");
    mSummaryTextView.setTypeface(tf);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if(view == mDeleteAccountButton) {
        createAlertDialog();
    }
}

public void deleteUser(String userEmail, String userPassword) {
    Firebase.ResultHandler handler = new Firebase.ResultHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            Toast.makeText(UserProfileActivity.this, "User deleted Successflly", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(UserProfileActivity.this, "There was an error, please try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    };
    mFirebaseRef.removeUser(userEmail, userPassword, handler );
}

public void createAlertDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(UserProfileActivity.this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = UserProfileActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.delete_user_dialog, null);
    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.delete_user_dialog, null));

    builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_message)
            .setTitle(R.string.dialog_title);
    builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            // User cancelled the dialog
        }
    });
    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.delete, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            // User clicked OK button
                String userEmail = mUserEmailEditText.getText().toString();
                String userPassword = mUserPasswordEditText.getText().toString();
                deleteUser(userEmail, userPassword);
        }
    });

    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
}
}
```

This is the layout for the activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.epicodus.concertaid.ui.UserProfileActivity"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/background1" />


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Account Details"
    android:textColor="#0288D1"
    android:id="@+id/summaryTextView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add Photo"
    android:textColor="#0288D1"
    android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
    android:id="@+id/addPhotoButton"
    android:layout_below="@+id/summaryTextView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/userPhotoImageView"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/addPhotoButton"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/current_user_s_image"
    android:src="@drawable/blank_user" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Change Email"
    android:textColor="#0288D1"
    android:id="@+id/changeEmailButton"
    android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
    android:layout_below="@+id/userPhotoImageView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Change Password"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textColor="#0288D1"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
    android:id="@+id/changePasswordEmailButton"
    android:layout_below="@+id/changeEmailButton"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Delete Account"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textColor="#0288D1"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:id="@+id/deleteAccountButton"
    android:layout_below="@+id/changePasswordEmailButton"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/buttonshape" />
```

Here is the layout for the AlertDialog:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/userEmailEditText"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:hint="Enter Email" />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/userPasswordEditText"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:hint="Enter Password"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Any example to show how to correctly Bind the `mUserEmailEditText` and `mUserPasswordEditText`

Thank you

Comment: post your `activity_user_profile.xml`

Comment: Reason of crash very clear with exception message: `Required view 'userEmailEditText' with ID 2131558627 for field 'mUserEmailEditText' was not found. If this view is optional add '@Nullable' annotation.`

Comment: @indramurari I have updated the post

Answer (score 1):

When you use bind like that is supposed to be from a existing ID in your activity layout, since you dont have it in your xml it will crash.. Dont bind the EditText and just create them in the AlertDialog, and im use setParams to change their layout

Comment: Can you please explain further, possibly provide a brief example of how I would create them within the AlertDialog and use setParams? I am unable to follow. I understand that those IDs are not in the layout file for the activity, but they are present in the layout file that I use to create the AlertDialog. I have updated my post to show the layout for the AlertDialog

Answer (score 0):

```
@Bind(R.id.userEmailEditText) EditText mUserEmailEditText;
@Bind(R.id.userPasswordEditText) EditText mUserPasswordEditText;
```

You can not bind the `view` from the `xml` which is not inflated as part of `Activity's view`. So remove @Bind from above line as follows.

```
EditText mUserEmailEditText;
EditText mUserPasswordEditText;
```

and `inflate` them while creating your `dialog` in `createAlertDialog()` method. So replace following 2 lines

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.delete_user_dialog, null);
builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.delete_user_dialog, null));
```

with

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.delete_user_dialog, null);
mUserEmailEditText = rootView.findViewById(R.id.userEmailEditText);
mUserPasswordEditText = rootView.findViewById(R.id.userPasswordEditText);
builder.setView(rootView);
```

Comment: So, your solution is not to use ButterKnife... O_O

Comment: @webo80 Please read answer carefully. Using `ButterKnife` or not is your choice. Using my answer as solution you can still use `ButterKnife` to bind views where I have binded them in simple way :-)